# Java receiving certificate %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN} from Apache headers

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, smartcard, apache2.2

I'm using Apache as reverse/proxy server. I've configured Apache 2.2 to require client certificate based authentication and I'm sending information of the certificate from Apache like this:

```
SSLRequireSSL
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 1

SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +StrictRequire +ExportCertData

RequestHeader set X-Client-DN %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}e
RequestHeader set X-Client-Verify %{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}e
```

I would like to receive those successfully to Java side..

I can see that those headers working fine, from Apache log file, but I'm still wondering how to receive those wanted headers to backend side. I'm using java se `request.getHeaderNames()` method and I can see headers from current page, but not those desired ones. I'm using ajp to receive headers from Apache..

The SSL handshake is made so many times and I can see many different headers from the log even "referred" by the same page.. Is it possible to save those specific headers somehow to session/stickysession so those would be readable since then when desired..?

Comment: What kind of framework & application server do you use on the "Java side"?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change:

```
RequestHeader set X-Client-DN %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}e
RequestHeader set X-Client-Verify %{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}e
```

By:

```
RequestHeader set X-Client-DN "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}s"
RequestHeader set X-Client-Verify "%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}s"
```

Answer (score 0):

Right answer was to set:

Header echo ^X-Client

To get desired headers to application (copies everything starting with "X-Client" from request headers to response headers)